# Argument of � has an extra } error from listings + hyperref

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, listings

I'm merging two previously working documents and came across this error (several instances of it, actually). I've reduced it into the following MWE, and it seems to be caused by some interaction between the listings and hyperref packages. If I remove the hyperref package (changing the order of imports doesn't seem to matter at all), everything works fine. The one thing I couldn't reduce much was the code I'm including. Also, it only happens with TexLive 2022, not TexLive 2021.

main.tex

```
\documentclass{article} %

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %
\usepackage{listings} %
\usepackage{hyperref} % comment this line for the error to disappear
\usepackage{color}
  \definecolor{keywordcolor}{rgb}{0.7, 0.1, 0.1}   % red
  \definecolor{tacticcolor}{rgb}{0.0, 0.1, 0.6}    % blue
  \definecolor{commentcolor}{rgb}{0.4, 0.4, 0.4}   % grey
  \definecolor{symbolcolor}{rgb}{0.0, 0.1, 0.6}    % blue
  \definecolor{sortcolor}{rgb}{0.1, 0.5, 0.1}      % green
  \definecolor{attributecolor}{rgb}{0.7, 0.1, 0.1} % red
\usepackage{amssymb} %

\def\lstlanguagefiles{lstlean.tex}

\lstnewenvironment{leancode}
  {\lstset{language=lean}} %
  {} %

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[language=lean]{zolt.lean}
\end{document}
```

zolt.lean (code I'm including with the listings package)

```
structure Point : Type

structure Segment : Type where
  p1 : Point
  p2 : Point
  neq : p1 ≠ p2

inductive PolySegment : Type where
| s₀ : PolySegment
| s₁ : Segment → PolySegment
| s₂ : PolySegment → PolySegment → PolySegment

opaque IsJordan : PolySegment → PolySegment → Prop

structure Face : Type where
  s1 : PolySegment
  s2 : PolySegment
  jordan : IsJordan s1 s2

inductive PolyFace : Type where
| f₀ : PolyFace
| f₁ : Face → PolyFace
| f₂ : PolyFace → PolyFace → PolyFace

opaque IsClosed : PolyFace → PolyFace → Prop

structure Volume : Type where
  vol1 : PolyFace
  vol2 : PolyFace
  closed : IsClosed vol1 vol2

inductive PolyVolume where
| v₀ : PolyVolume
| v₁ : Volume → PolyVolume
| v₂ : PolyVolume → PolyVolume → PolyVolume

opaque PolyVolume.HasFaceIntersection
  : PolyVolume → PolyVolume → Prop

axiom PolyVolume.EmptyAlwaysHasFaceIntersection {v : PolyVolume} :
  HasFaceIntersection v₀ v

axiom PolyVolume.HasFaceIntersection_comm {v u : PolyVolume} :
  HasFaceIntersection v u → HasFaceIntersection u v

def PolyVolume.NonEmpty : PolyVolume → Prop
| v₀ => False
| v₁ _ => True
| v₂ _ _ => True

class Zₚ (a : Type u) where
  ε : a
  cmp : a → a → Prop
  join : (p : a) → (q : a) → cmp p q → a
  NonEmpty : a → Prop
```

You also need [lstlean.tex](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanprover/lean4/master/doc/latex/lstlean.tex) for Lean language definitions.

I can't afford to not include hyperref in my actual document, so I'm out of options. The relevant raw logs are:

```
! Argument of � has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.52  
       ε : a
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before � was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.52  
       ε : a
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Argument of � has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.52  
       ε : a
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before � was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.52  
       ε : a
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Argument of � has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.52  
       ε : a
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before � was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.52  
       ε : a
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Argument of � has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.52  
       ε : a
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before � was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.52  
       ε : a
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

Comment: your language file sets `extendedchars=false` and at page breaks that confuses hyperref which has to extends utf8 chars then. With `extendedchars=true` your file compiles.

Comment: Yep, that seems to be it. Thank you very much! I didn't think this option of `extendedchars` would matter since all the non-ascii characters are exchanged to latex commands (using the `literate` option). Now I wonder why the language file has this, it's strange that no one ran into this problem before… Anyway, do you want to make this an answer so I can accept it? PS: it makes sense that it had something to do with the page breaks too since I couldn't isolate the problem to any specific part of text.